# Why does the backshifting of tenses rule not apply here?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses, backshifting

Why does the backshifting of tenses rule not apply to this sentence?:

*"I forgot what a liar he is."*

Because the verb *"forgot"* in the main clause is past tense, shouldn't the verb in the noun clause (*"is"*) be past tense, too?

Yet I see sentences like my example, which start with "I forgot" or "I had forgotten" and then use present-tense verbs, all the time.

Comment: If you don't want to imply that he was a liar only in the past, you'll refer to what a liar **he is**. I forgot what a liar he is.

Comment: I think the "backshifting of tenses rule" is something to help ESL learners.  Maybe you can get better explanation at ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Because the state of affairs referred to in the embedded clause is timeless, or continues to the present.

In such cases, but *was* and *is* are possible, depending on whether the speaker is wanting to focus on how things were at the time, or to acknowledge how things were and continue to be.